# CodeIgniter and normal website

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter-2, web-hosting

I have a web hosting which hold  a website I run.

I'm learning CodeIgniter so I would like to upload it a file in that web hosting and run some test and learn, CodeIgniter just for test, and keep using the website normally for users.

Is there any related or known issues or problem by running both ?  I don't want the website to get frozen or act weird wit this.

Comment: I think no issue, but what you want to do?

Comment: create sub domain and install codeigniter for learning!!!

Answer (score 2):

Install codeigniter in it's own folder in a subdirectory instead of in the web root directory.

You will have to modify your config:
[Installing a CodeIgniter application in a subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197119/installing-a-codeigniter-application-in-a-subfolder)

Answer (score 0):

Create a New Folder for your CodeIgniter Learning and Upload all CI files there including System folder and other.

If you Upload the the files with current website files folder it may create some issue.